# Two versions of python 2.x installed on the same system

Tags: fedora, python

I'm working on Fedora 21 and, don't ask me why, but I have two versions of Python 2.x installed on it. I can tell that I have two different versions because when I call it from the terminal with "python", I get:

> Python 2.7.9 (default, Feb 18 2017, 17:18:34)
>
> [GCC 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6)] on linux2
>
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

I'd like to add that the version that I call with "python" is "/usr/local/bin/python". On the other hand, when I call it with "/usr/bin/python", I get:

> Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 24 2015, 18:25:44)
>
> [GCC 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6)] on linux2
>
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

On top of that, they don't seem to have access to the same libraries/modules. For example, if I run a script using SciPy with "python" it raises an error, while that's not the case if I run it with "/usr/bin/python".

So, how do I get rid of the version running when I call it with "python" and keep the one that I call with "/usr/bin/python"? Moreover, I'd like to call the one that I'm curently calling with "/usr/bin/python" with a simple "python".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attempt to remove the one under /usr/local/bin/python by finding out what RPM installed it:

```
rpm -f /usr/local/bin/python
```

Once you have one version only it will be the one called.

Two other options are:
a) Modify your PATH variable so that /usr/bin comes before /usr/local/bin
b) Alias 'python' to '/usr/bin/python'

Comment: Thanks. I did "rpm -qf /usr/local/bin/python" and I got "file /usr/local/bin/python is not owned by any package". How should I proceed to uninstall it?

Comment: I'm this case it could probably just be removed. However, /use/local is often where people install software and scripts manually. Someone may have put it there for a reason. Another option would be to simply rename this one to 'python279' (or anything other than 'python').

Comment: And what about the fact that "/usr/local/bin/python" is unable to see modules that "/usr/bin/python" can see? What is the explanation for that?

Comment: Python uses a search path similar to the system shell. Most of it is built in to the python executable. You can view it interactively:
`# python`,
`>>> import sys`,
`>>> sys.path`,
See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path

Answer (score 2):

There's no real reason to delete one of the Pythons (other applications may depend on it).

To use `/usr/bin/python` by default, make sure that `/usr/bin` comes before `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH`.

You may investigate this with `echo $PATH` and it's possible to simply add `/usr/bin` to the front of that value with

```
PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

in your shell startup files.  Having `/usr/bin` listed multiple times in `$PATH` is not an issue.

If you write Python scripts, just make sure that the shebang-line reads

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

and that the script is executable.  This will make it pick up the Python interpreter that you want.